# Glibc error: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument

Tags: glibc, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I'm attempting to load a dynamic library at runtime using dlopen.  I am calling it like this:

```
dlopen("/absolute/path/to/libFoo.so", 0);
```

And this yields the following error:

```
invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument
```

This code works perfectly on macOS, but fails on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.  What is the meaning of this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

> This code works perfectly on macOS

That doesn't mean it has no bugs.

> What is the meaning of this error, and how can I fix it?

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html): One of the following two values **must** be included in flags: `RTLD_LAZY`, `RTLD_NOW`.

You didn't include either flag, and that is a bug in your program, which GLIBC is telling you about.

To fix it, replace `0` with either `RTLD_LAZY` or `RTLD_NOW`, whichever is appropriate for your program.